# Automate the process of exporting job run logs to DBFS

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

How to export the logs for your job run in databricks?it should automatically deliver the logs to DBFS.

Comment: Hi @John, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To automate this process, you can set up your job so that it automatically delivers logs to DBFS through the Job API. Explained in method2

**Method1:** Manually you enable cluster logging through Azure Databricks UI

In the Azure portal navigate to Job > Configure Cluster. Under Advanced Options click Logging. Enter the following information.

Destination: Select DBFS.

CLuster Log Path: Enter dbfs:/cluster-logs.

[image]

**Method2:** Automate using Azure Databricks Job API

Using the /api/2.0/jobs/create specify the following in the request body.

```
{
    "new_cluster": {
        "cluster_log_conf": {
                "dbfs": {
                    "destination": "dbfs:/cluster-logs"
                }
         }
    }
}
```

For more information, see the [NewCluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#jobsclusterspecnewcluster) and [ClusterLogConf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters#clusterclusterlogconf) fields in the Job [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#jobsjobsservicecreatejob) API call.